# How to let vue component wait until the data is ready for render?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

vue component won't wait for data from controller using axios get, it prompt error:

index.vue?d4c7:200 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'ftth' of undefined

my code are below:

```
<template>
    <div class="dashboard-editor-container">
        <el-row style="background:#fff;padding:16px 16px 0;margin-bottom:32px;">
            <line-chart :chart-data="lineChartData"/>
        </el-row>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import LineChart from './components/LineChart';
    import axios from 'axios';

    const lineChartData = {
        all: {
            FTTHData: [],
            VDSLData: [],
            ADSLData: [],
        },
    };
    export default {
        name: 'Dashboard',
        components: {
            LineChart,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                lineChartData: lineChartData.all,
            };
        },
        created() {
            this.getData();
        },
        methods: {
            handleSetLineChartData(type) {
                this.lineChartData = lineChartData[type];
            },
            async getData() {
                axios
                    .get('/api/data_graphs')
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response.data);
                        var data = response.data;
                        var i = 0;
                        for (i = Object.keys(data).length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                            lineChartData.all.FTTHData.push(data[i]['ftth']);
                            lineChartData.all.VDSLData.push(data[i]['vdsl']);
                            lineChartData.all.ADSLData.push(data[i]['adsl']);
                        }
                    });
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

> Do I have to use watch method?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Use v-if and v-else to determine whether to show components or not. I show a loading component prior to data being retrieved from server

Comment: You are using async without await but not the issue here. What does console.log print?

Comment: when console.log "data[i]['ftth']" it says "index.vue?d4c7:207 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'ftth' of undefined at eval". Maybe because I use foreach in my controller that is why it takes time to pass data to vue?

Comment: @Savlon, after a lot of debugging. Thank you for the help :) I also use axios timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, because you have such a nested data structure you'll want a computed property to return whether the data is loaded or not. Normally, you could do this check in the template.

```
computed: {
  isDataLoaded() {
    const nestedLoaded = Object.keys(this.lineChartData).map(key => this.lineChartData[key].length !== 0)
    return this.lineChartData && nestedLoaded.length !== 0
  }
}
```

You can use `v-if="isDataLoaded"` to hide the element until the data has been loaded.

Comment: You are a genius, it works. Didn't use timeout in axios. Thank you for this code :)

Comment: do you know how to let vue-component wait for more than a minute before rendering data? my query to database takes more than 1 minute.

Comment: I'm not sure if any user would sit around for 1 minute waiting for your data to load. You'd better look at ways to optimize your query, and/or handle it in the background while letting the user do other things in your app.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly clear how `response.data` looks like, but because you're using `Object.keys` I'm assuming it's an object.

If you need to loop over the keys then when using numeric indexes you most likely won't get an object. So you need to get the `key` and index `i` and use that value to access the object. Change this:

```
for (i = Object.keys(data).length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  lineChartData.all.FTTHData.push(data[i]['ftth']);
  lineChartData.all.VDSLData.push(data[i]['vdsl']);
  lineChartData.all.ADSLData.push(data[i]['adsl']);
}
```

to this:

```
const keys = Object.keys(data)
for (i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  lineChartData.all.FTTHData.push(data[keys[i]]['ftth']);
  lineChartData.all.VDSLData.push(data[keys[i]]['vdsl']);
  lineChartData.all.ADSLData.push(data[keys[i]]['adsl']);
}
```

But for looping over object's keys is easier to use this:

```
for (let key in data) {
  lineChartData.all.FTTHData.push(data[key]['ftth']);
  lineChartData.all.VDSLData.push(data[key]['vdsl']);
  lineChartData.all.ADSLData.push(data[key]['adsl']);
}
```

The alternative syntax will feed you keys and in my opinion is easier to read.

Comment: your answer is useful :)

Answer (score 0):

For the mean time:

> Use set Axios Timeout 5000ms

```
axios
.get('/api/data_graphs', { timeout: 5000 })
.then(response => {
  console.log(response.data);
  var data = response.data;
  var i = 0;
  for (i = Object.keys(data).length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    lineChartData.all.FTTHData.push(data[i]['ftth']);
    lineChartData.all.VDSLData.push(data[i]['vdsl']);
    lineChartData.all.ADSLData.push(data[i]['adsl']);
  }
  this.lineChartIsLoaded = true;
});
```

> Use v-if in vue component

```
<line-chart v-if="lineChartIsLoaded" :chart-data="lineChartData" :date-data="dateData" />
```

> Set lineChartIsLoaded to false at default

```
const lineChartIsLoaded = false;
```

Comment: Using a 5 second timer is a race condition; not inherently solving the problem if it takes longer than 5 seconds, and a big hit to your user experience.

Comment: that is also what I experience but for now I will use it since I'm still looking for solutions about it.

Comment: I misread, I thought you were using setTimeout. The axios setting timeout is just when axios decides to stop trying to get the data. You should be able to remove it without problem. Using `v-if` and a `isLoaded` variable is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can write dummy data in your data properties before real ones are loading

```
all: {
  FTTHData: ["Loading..."],
  VDSLData: ["Loading..."],
  ADSLData: ["Loading..."],
},
```